# Find the coordinates of the matrix after a reflection in the given line.

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

$$\left[\begin{matrix}-8 & 1 & -7\\ -7 & -5 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$
The given line is the y axis.

I cannot show my work for I have no clue on how to solve this.

Comment: If the points in the matrix are $(-8, -7)$, $(1, -5)$ and $(-7,1)$, then reflection through the $y$-axis would make all the $x$ coordinates negative, and your points would map to $(8, -7)$, $(-1, -5)$ and $(7, 1)$.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thanks. :)